# reading CSV file till particular column numbers

Tags: java, csv

I am reading  csv file method as under -

```
public ArrayList<String> fileRead(File f) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ArrayList<String> CSVData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String text;
        try {
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                CSVData.add(text);
                log.debug(text);
            }
            log.info(f + ": Read successfully");

            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error in reading file " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return CSVData;
    }
```

but I want to read file  till defined column number e.g. till 20th column,
but if in between I will found empty cell for some column then as above code it will exit on  (text = br.readLine()) != null ,
so finally my question is how to read CSV file till particular columns either its empty cell or whatever it should read till those column and break point for moving next line should be that column example 20th column ,

Thank in advance for help and support

Comment: Please show a couple of lines of your csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [uniVocity-parsers' column selection feature](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/#column-selection) to process your file.

Here's an example:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.selectFields("Foo", "Bar", "Blah");
// or if your file does not have a row with column headers, you can use indexes:
parserSettings.selectIndexes(4, 20, 2);
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(f));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Do NOT try to parse a CSV by yourself. There are many intricacies there. For example, using code such as the one you pasted:

```
while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Will break as soon as your CSV has values that contain newline characters.

Comment: Hi, I am trying since last 2 Hours but                     import com.univocity.parsers.csv.*;                   is not resolving even I have added in my pom.xml as under, I am not able to go-ahead, I would like to request Please can you send me sample code because as this API is new I am not able to find examples in Google, <dependency>
 <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
 <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: The library is on the maven central repository for quite some time now. Possibly your Pom.xml is broken. In any case, just download the jar file from www.univocity.com

Comment: Hi, when I am using uniVocity-parser code as under -I am getting compiler error  
public class CsvParserExamples {
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows =parser.parseAll(getReader("mycsv.csv"));
}}                                                                 Syntax error on token "getFormat", Identifier expected after this token,The method getReader(String) is undefined for the type CsvParserExamples- Watchpoint:CsvParserExamples [access and modification] - allRows

Comment: If you could put this code inside a method, instead of the class body, that'll be great.